# How to sign Expo app APK to update existing App on Google Play Store?

Tags: android, react-native, apk, expo

I have an EXPO app and I already created and published it on Google Play Store. The Google App Signing is activated for this project. Now I want to update this APK in this project. I used the command 'expo build:android' to build the updated APK. But when I send it to my project on Play store, it says that the certificate is wrong ('Upload failed You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you chose to let Expo handle the process: Clear the credentials, let Expo handle the process, and fetch the upload key. Contact google (you find the contact options in Play Console at the area “Google App Signing”. Once you filled the form, they will write you and ask for the new PEM with instructions to get it. You can follow the instructions or just chose to let Expo handle it (its easier). Reply to the email and add the fetched upload-cert as attachment. Wait 2-3 business days. Upload your generated APK.

Answer (score 1):

You must change your app **slug back** to the old one, you should then be able to fetch your old keystore from our servers by running expo fetch:android:keystore

Answer (score 0):

When you are signing your app you use a `keystore` file and credentials. You need to use the same file to sign your app again. I am sorry to be the one telling you this but if you can not find that file, your app is going to be one of the many orphant apps in the store.

You can read more about this [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)

Good luck!

Comment: I don't remember signing my app manually. When I built my expo app for the first time with 'expo build:android', I choose the option to let expo handle the signing stuff. And when a created my app project at Google Play Console, I choose to use the 'Google App Signing'. I guess I'm missing something. Can you tell me how does this Keystore file look like and where should I get it?

Comment: By the way, I have here my private_key inside a json file called (api-'a bunch of numbers and letters'.json).  That's what I received from Google. Is that my keystore?

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: @Anderson I have the same issue - can you share how you solved this?

Comment: @Rich https://forums.expo.io/t/how-to-sign-expo-app-apk-to-update-existing-app-on-google-play-store/31753